# Which youtube credentials should I use?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I just want to fetch some data from the playlist, to make it work. Which Credentials do I need to use?

1. API keys
2. OAuth 2.0 client ID

Answer (score 0):

If you are just getting playlist, searching YouTube videos via keyword or listing videos you can use API keys, but if you have to upload videos or access private user data you have to use OAuth 2.0 client ID.

> - **OAuth 2.0**: Your application must send an OAuth 2.0 token with any request that accesses private user data. Your application sends a client ID and, possibly, a client secret to obtain a token. You can generate OAuth 2.0 credentials for web applications, service accounts, or installed applications.
>
> See the [Creating OAuth 2.0 credentials](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application#Create_OAuth2_Tokens) section for more information.
>
> - **API keys**: A request that does not provide an OAuth 2.0 token must send an API key. The key identifies your project and provides API access, quota, and reports.
>
> See the [Creating API Keys section](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application#Create_API_Keys) for information about creating an API key.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is the meaning of this "A request that does not provide an OAuth 2.0 token must send an API key"?

Comment: I have also tried using the API keys, but that is not working for me.